# How to rewrite this sql statement using prisma syntax?

Tags: sql, prisma

How to rewrite the sql statement using prisma syntax below?

```
    const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 6;

    const invoices = await sql`
      SELECT
        invoices.id,
        invoices.amount,
        invoices.date,
        invoices.status,
        customers.name,
        customers.email,
        customers.image_url
      FROM invoices
      JOIN customers ON invoices.customer_id = customers.id
      WHERE
        customers.name ILIKE ${`%${query}%`} OR
        customers.email ILIKE ${`%${query}%`} OR
        invoices.amount::text ILIKE ${`%${query}%`} OR
        invoices.date::text ILIKE ${`%${query}%`} OR
        invoices.status ILIKE ${`%${query}%`}
      ORDER BY invoices.date DESC
      LIMIT ${ITEMS_PER_PAGE} OFFSET ${offset}
    `;
```

I didn't find the corresponding syntax of `amount::text` and `date::text`.